# Azure B2C setup

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to set up Azure AD B2C for my web app.

I've already created a tenant. I then created an app. According to articles I'm following, I should then be able to click "API Access" and add scopes. In my case, there's nothing under API drop down:
[image]

I already see "Access the user's profile" with the following selected:
[image]

Under "Published Scopes", again, I see nothing:
[image]

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

After adding the App ID URI, I was able to move forward a bit but still not sure about published scopes. This is what I currently have:

[image]

And under API Access, this is what I have:
[image]

Basically, the behavior I'm getting on my frontend app which is built on ReactJs is that I hit the Azure AD B2C login. After entering my credentials, I get redirected to my app. I see `id_token` in the URL but the `MSAL` library I'm using doesn't capture the token -- I have a break point in my React code to see if I'm capturing the token. I get sent back to the login screen on Azure, then back to my app. On the third one, I actually see the token being captured but I end up with the following errors:
[image]

I'm using this library which is a wrapper for the `MSAL.js` library: https://github.com/jamesrandall/react-azure-adb2c

I'm pretty certain there are config errors. Just not sure what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**API access** is used to assign access from a web app to an API app.

**Published scopes** is used to register the access scopes for the API app.

Before the access scopes can be registered for the API app, an **App ID URI** must be set as the resource identifier for the API app, as described by [the Azure Active Directory B2C: Register your application article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-api).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the App ID URI and was able to move forward a bit but still unable to use the token to call my ASP.NET Core API backend. Please see the detailed info I added to the original post under UPDATE. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you registered your ASP.NET Core API app with Azure AD B2C? It is to this app registration that you must add the access scopes.

Comment: Yes, I did. The "Published Scopes" and "Api Access" images posted here are under my registered app.

Comment: If you have registered the API app and set the published scopes for it and also registered the web app and set the API access for it, then the web app must then request an access token with the permitted scopes using the `scopes` option in the authentication library.

Comment: @Sam How did you go?

Comment: Just got it working. Your response helped me get Azure AD B2C setup right but my front end app couldn't use the token due to a few configuration mistakes I was making. Anyway, just got it working minutes ago. Thank you for your help!